# Missing Ctor sonar issue with Lombok

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, sonarqube, lombok, checkstyle

I have gradle(6.9) springboot(2.7.0) project with following dependecy

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
```

while analysis with sonar (version is 8.9) it shows Missing Ctor rule
even if i had used @NoArgsConstructor it shows Class should define a constructor.The same error shows for entity class annotated with @Entity

I have tried to add the following in sonar-project.properties

```
sonar.java.libraries=build/resources/main/META-INF/resources/lombok.jar
```

and the following in build.gradle

```
property "sonar.java.libraries","build/resources/main/META-INF/resources/lombok-1.18.22.jar"
```

but not working.

given the following in the lombok.config

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

it will helps only to improve the coverage of @NoArgsConstructor,@Getter etc

I found that .class file having the generated constructor but sonar is not analysing this properly.That sonar rule is from checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.MissingCtorCheck

I can't suppress this rule.expecting other solutions for this

Comment: Looks like you missed to add `compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'`

Comment: i forget to add here.actually it already there in build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many days of effort, I got the solution.

Usage of lombok is stepping on checkstyle limitation https://checkstyle.org/writingchecks.html#Limitations  read single file as text, checkstyle is not type-aware tool.That's why the binaries,classpath dependencies were not taken on that version.I found that this rule is generated by sonar checkstyle by analyzing the checkstyle-result.xml in the build folder.This will resolved in latest version.
I have upgraded the **sonar to  10.1** version and **checkstyle 10.12.1**.Now the issue resolved